# Creating clean Oracle SQL view without repeating same information in each row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created an Oracle SQL view which looks like this:

```
John Strange  |  Carnaby Street, S9 8EU | CS5 Degree | Sociology   
John Strange  |  Carnaby Street, S9 8EU | CS5 Degree | Religious Studies  
John Strange  |  Carnaby Street, S9 8EU | CS5 Degree | Environmental Studies  
John Strange  |  Carnaby Street, S9 8EU | CS5 Degree | Management  
John Strange  |  Carnaby Street, S9 8EU | CS5 Degree | Business Intelligence
```

What would you recommend using in order to display name, address and degree name only once? I have used DISTINCT but it does not work.

Comment: Going in a different direction than the other answers. You could normalize a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Why it doesn't work you just exclude the other columns because `distinct` will applies to all columns/expression that you have express.

```
select distinct displayname, address, degree 
from <view> v1;
```

For instance last column has different value. so, it will not work if you have include in `select` statement with `distinct`.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c113/3/0

You can define your view query as follows -

Setup -

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Name varchar2(12), Address varchar2(22), Degree varchar2(10), Subject varchar2(21))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (Name, Address, Degree, Subject)
         VALUES ('John Strange', 'Carnaby Street, S9 8EU', 'CS5 Degree', 'Sociology')
    INTO Table1 (Name, Address, Degree, Subject)
         VALUES ('John Strange', 'Carnaby Street, S9 8EU', 'CS5 Degree', 'Religious Studies')
    INTO Table1 (Name, Address, Degree, Subject)
         VALUES ('John Strange', 'Carnaby Street, S9 8EU', 'CS5 Degree', 'Environmental Studies')
    INTO Table1 (Name, Address, Degree, Subject)
         VALUES ('John Strange', 'Carnaby Street, S9 8EU', 'CS5 Degree', 'Management')
    INTO Table1 (Name, Address, Degree, Subject)
         VALUES ('John Strange', 'Carnaby Street, S9 8EU', 'CS5 Degree', 'Business Intelligence')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Query -

```
select name, address, degree, listagg(Subject,' , ') within group (order by subject) as Subjects
from Table1
group by name, address, degree
```

Output -

```
NAME            ADDRESS                 DEGREE      SUBJECTS
John Strange    Carnaby Street, S9 8EU  CS5 Degree  Business Intelligence , Environmental Studies , Management , Religious Studies , Sociology
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, instead of removing the fourth column, you might want to display a list of the values. You can use LISTAGG for that, although keep in mind that it has a 4000 character limit.

```
select full_name, address, program, 
    listagg(course, ', ') within group (order by course)
from my_view
group by full_name, address, program;
```